UAC shield on icon stops the icon scaling in folder view
After many days of searching, I couldn't find the answer anywhere.
I've created a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio 2022. I have an icon that scales correctly when I zoom in folder view.
Now, my app needs to run with the administrator privileges. To do that, I changed the required permissions in the manifest from asInvoker to requireAdministrator. After this, the app icon contains the UAC shield badge, which is expected and desired. However, this also prevents the icon to scale correctly - it's always the smallest size, and when the view is increased in the folder, the icon is just a small icon surrounded by empty space in the tile.
Is there something else that needs to be done when making the icon to work with the UAC shield badge? Is it the Visual Studio issue perhaps? I set the icon in the project properties, it's stored in the resources.
I've tried changing the icons in the ico file, using single size, different sizes, using the resource file instead of the manifest (but I need this to run as admin), clearing caches, rebuilding, clearing and building the solution again.

The ADC shield icon is contained in System. Drawing namespace which supports these typical sizes: 16 pixels x 16 pixels, 32 pixels x 32 pixels, 48 pixels x 48 pixels. Refer to the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemicons.shield?view=net-8.0
You may need to customize it if you need a different size of the shield icon.

@paweldev1 Any feedback?
